# My void is not getting recognized by Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[It shows there and the xml recognizes it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLTWp.png)

[But there it says no use, and when I use the button it crashes I certainly don't know what is wrong I used an Android Studio template for creating the app, the Navigation Drawe Views Activity and used the presets for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwXXA.png)
[These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1CVh.png)

Comment: `onClick` in XML doesn't work in Fragments.